# Creating infinite loop with animate for topscroll

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop a function/animation. I want a page to scroll to bottom, then jump to top and do it infinitly.
I have code that does that but only one time:

```
$(document).ready(pagescroll);
function pagescroll() {
    var z = document.getElementById('main_container').clientHeight + 2400;
    var speed = z * 2;
    window.scroll(0,0);
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: z }, { easing: "linear", duration: speed });
}
```

`main_container` is a div stretching across the page. I tried adding `pagescroll();` after `animate`, removing `window.scroll(0,0)`, and adding both `pagescroll` and `pagescroll()` after `duration:speed`, putting everything in a `setTimeout`, but nothing worked. Each example I found didn't work. How can I add a infinite loop to this function?

Comment: Kind of weird behaviour you are looking for but who knows...

Comment: It is not to be implemented od website- basicly it is like end credits where someone can easily add names to XML file and display it in loop. Whole thing will be projected on wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add callback to your `animate` function, like this:

```
$('body,html').animate(
    {scrollTop: z},
    {easing: "linear", duration: speed}, 
    function() {
        $('body,html').scrollTop( 0 ); // scroll to top when animation finished
        pagescroll(); // call scroll function again
    }
);
```

In this case your function will work in recursive way.

Comment: It scrolls to to said position, but it is not jumping back to top.

Comment: @user2584809 try adding `window.scroll(0,0);` before `$('body,html').scrollTop( 0 );`

Comment: Still nothing. It looks like after finishing animation, it is not calling other function (I changed whole scrolling callback to simple alert and nothing happend). I also changed it for test purpose so it has constant topscroll position and duration.

Comment: Can you create come jsFiddle example or something?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/fotw070n/ It is not exacly same thing, because I'm generating "text" paragrafs by importing data from XML file.

Comment: See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fotw070n/1/ I have changed `{easing: "linear", duration: speed}` to just number as jUqey animate accept string ad duration, not object: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and removed animation for html as it's causes to callback run twice.

Comment: Everything is working now, thanks. But isn't animation working now in easing mode, not linear?